# Accessing a Variable from an Activity to a RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am new to android  , I have two classes an **Activity** class `BureauRateListing.java` and an **Adapter** class `CurrencySelectorAdapter.java`.

So i want to access this variable (`public String bs;`)from an Activity class to a `RecyclerView Adapter` class in the `onBindViewHolder()` method, below is my Activity class:

```
        public String bs;
        private Intent i;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.rate_recycler_view);

            raterv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.raterv_rv);
            i = getIntent();

            bs = i.getStringExtra("buysell");

}
```

Now how can i access the **variable** (`public String bs;`) from an **`Activity class`** to an Adapter class inside `onBindViewHolder()` method, and i send it as an Extra to the NextActivity.  Below is my `onBindViewHolder()` method where i want to access the **variable** and i send it as an **Extra** :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CurrencyViewHolder holder, int position) {



        final  BureauRateObject br = itemList.get(position);
        holder.bureauname.setText(br.getBureau_name());
        holder.rates.setText(br.getBuysell());

        final String BureauId = br.getBureau_id();
        final String BureauName = br.getBureau_name();
        final String BureauPhone = br.getBureau_phone();
        final String BureauEmail = br.getBureau_email();
        final String  Website = br.getWebsite();
        final String Branches = br.getBranches();
        final String BureauProfile = br.getBureau_profile();
        final String BureauLogo = br.getBureau_logo();
        final String BureauPhoto = br.getBureau_photo();
        final String currency = br.getBuysell();
        final String BuySell = "Buying";
        final String BuySell_two ="Selling";





        holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent i = new Intent(CurrencySelectorAdapter.this.context, SingleForexDetails.class);
               // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("bureau_id", BureauId);
                i.putExtra("bureau_name",BureauName);
                i.putExtra("bureau_phone",BureauPhone);
                i.putExtra("bureau_email",BureauEmail);
                i.putExtra("website",Website);
                i.putExtra("branches",Branches);
                i.putExtra("bureau_profile",BureauProfile);
                i.putExtra("bureau_logo",BureauLogo);
                i.putExtra("bureau_photo",BureauPhoto);
                i.putExtra("currency",currency);
                i.putExtra("Buying",BuySell);
                i.putExtra("Selling",BuySell_two);
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: send variable in adapter class Constructor.this way you can access it

Comment: @Divyesh, thanks but can make me a small edit

Comment: declare variable as public static String bs; and access it in adapter class with respect to class name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
BureauRateListing extends Activity{
 public String bs;
        private Intent i;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.rate_recycler_view);

            raterv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.raterv_rv);
            i = getIntent();

            bs = i.getStringExtra("buysell");
       }

       public string getbs(){
         return bs;
      }
}


CurrencySelectorAdapter extends ...{

    BureauRateListing mBureauRateListing;    // it's Activity

    CurrencySelectorAdapter (Activity activity){
        mBureauRateListing =activity;
    }
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CurrencyViewHolder holder, int position) {
          String bs = mBureauRateListing.getbs();
          .
          .
          .
    }
```

Comment: I tried this attempt , but my question is when i try to send it an extra in the onBindViewHolder , it seems the string is empty , what should i do. The App crashes and brings NPE

Comment: What i am meaning i want that accessed variable to come holding an attached extra , but it seems it comes when its null, what should i do. –

Answer (score 2):

in MainActivity.java

```
public static String bs;
```

in RecycleViewAdapter.java

```
import static <app path>.MainActivity.bs;
```

now it is accessable.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Activity in Adapter Class.

Used this syntax for accessing bs variable in Adapter.

```
BureauRateListing extends Activity{
    public String bs;
    private Intent i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rate_recycler_view);
        CurrencySelectorAdapter currencySelectorAdapter=new (BureauRateListing.this);
        raterv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.raterv_rv);
        i = getIntent();
        bs = i.getStringExtra("buysell");
   }}

CurrencySelectorAdapter extends ...{
Activity mBureauRateListing;    // it's Activity
CurrencySelectorAdapter (Activity activity){
    mBureauRateListing =activity;
}
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CurrencyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      String bsFromActivity = ((BureauRateListing)mBureauRateListing).bs;
}}
```

Comment: is that the only code to be done ?, please am new in android can you make me a small edit according to my question to your answer thanks

Comment: What i am meaning i want that accessed  variable to come holding an attached extra , but it seems it comes when its null, what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

Better to start the new activity in your  `BureauRateListing` activity itself. Avoid the `startActivity` from adapter. You could create an `View.OnClickListener`  member in adapter , provide a setter for the same in adapter `setOnClickListener`. And from your activity you can set this listener directly.  `adapter.setOnClikListener(this)`. Implement `View.OnClickListener` in activity , and in `onClick` start the new activity.

In your adapter add

```
private View.OnClickListener mCLickListener;
```

Also add

```
 public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
   mCLickListener = listener;
 }
```

In onBindViewHolder

```
holder.root.setOnClickListener(mCLickListener)
```

make  your `BureauRateListingActivity` implements `View.OnClickListener`

Then , in `BureauRateListingActivity` inside `onClick` method

```
       Intent i = new Intent(this, SingleForexDetails.class);
           // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("bureau_id", BureauId);
            i.putExtra("bureau_name",BureauName);
            i.putExtra("bureau_phone",BureauPhone);
            i.putExtra("bureau_email",BureauEmail);
            i.putExtra("website",Website);
            i.putExtra("branches",Branches);
            i.putExtra("bureau_profile",BureauProfile);
            i.putExtra("bureau_logo",BureauLogo);
            i.putExtra("bureau_photo",BureauPhoto);
            i.putExtra("currency",currency);
            i.putExtra("Buying",BuySell);
            i.putExtra("Selling",BuySell_two);
            startActivity(i);
```

Finally in your `BureauRateListingActivity` set the listener in adapter
`adapter.setOnClikListener(this).`

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor of your adapter get an instance of **BureauRateListing.java** class and store it in a member variable

```
BureauRateListing mAct;
public CurrencySelectorAdapter(BureauRateListing act){
    this.mAct = act;

}
```

now you can access the **public instance variables of BureauRateListing** class using mAct from any method of **CurrencySelectorAdapter** class.

for eg

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CurrencyViewHolder holder, int position) {
String s = mAct.bs;
}
```

Comment: I tried this attempt @Majeed  , but my question is when i try to send String s; as  an extra to the NextActivity  in the onBindViewHolder , it seems the string is empty, the App crashes and brings NPE  , what should i do